# Use Theme.Light Datepicker on Theme.Holo.Light

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have an activity that uses Theme.Holo.Light containing EditText, RadioButtons and DatePicker. I want to use Theme.Holo.Light for entire activity, except DatePicker which I want to be Theme.Light style. How can I do this?

Comment: Check the documentation on themes and styles:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Hello, can you tell me the exact place to look which helps me to solve my problem? I did not find what I need, maybe I don't see it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    style="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker"/>
```

?

Holo uses `@android:style/Widget.Holo.DatePicker` while `@android:style/Widget.DatePicker` is the one you need to use.

Links:

[Style list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

[Style list's source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

Update:

It seems that DatePicker is built with 3 NumberPickers. My answer is correct, but it is incomplete. The best approach I found to solve your problem was to recreate ans make your own DatePicker (copypaste from source code) and give style to the DatePicker AND the 3 NumberPickers inside.

Link of the Layout on GitHub:

[DatePicker Layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker.xml)

Comment: If I change in manifest from my custom holo theme to Theme Light `<activity
           ..
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            ..
        </activity>` datepicker works fine but as expected, entire activity uses Theme.Light. If I put back in Manifest Theme Holo Light and add in myactivity.xml `<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            style="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />` it still uses Theme.Holo.Light DatePicker

Comment: Nonono, leave your manifest as `Theme.Holo.Light.NoTitleBar`. Just Use the Theme.Light on your datePicker (without the noTitleBar)

Comment: Still not working. In myactivity.xml I have now `<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            style="@android:style/Theme.Light"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Comment: Still displays Holo.Light DatePicker `<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Comment: No :/ Idk what else can it be. Let my try it on a Test Project and I'll answer if I manage to do it.

Comment: I can't test it now since I'm on my phone, but I'll do it tomorrow. Can you try creating an xml style with `@android:style/Widget.DatePicker` as a parent? Then, use that style you just created and use it.

Comment: It seems that DatePicker is built with 3 NumberPickers. My answer is correct, but it is incomplete. The best approach I found to solve your problem was to recreate ans make your own DatePicker (copypaste from source code) and give style to the DatePicker AND the 3 NumberPickers inside https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker.xml